# Gazebo shutdown (BadDrawable)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Occasionally gazebo crashes with a BadDrawable error, but the crash seems to be unrelated to anything else I do - I have been able to repeat the command and gazebo launches fine, but sometimes the error repeats once, twice, or more.
Has anyone else had a similar problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27952/gazebo-shutdown-(baddrawable)/) by [jfetsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1816/jfetsch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-20**:
What kind of graphics hardware are you running?

**Comment by [jfetsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1816/jfetsch/) on 2012-02-25**:
Mobile Intel 4 Series Express Chipset - just the default graphics card that came on my laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many Intel graphics cards have difficulty in running Gazebo. This would cause your error. See [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/SystemRequirements) for a list of supported hardware.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jfetsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1816/jfetsch/) on 2012-02-27**:
Thank you, that's what I was afraid of. At least I know what the problem is though

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-02-27**:
I wonder if this is related, can some one test it out by disabling sync to vblank?  thanks.  http://www.preshweb.co.uk/2011/05/ubuntu-11-04-x-freezing-after-screensaver-active-laptop-lid-closed/